# C#. How do I drag and drop table adapter to Windows Form when it is Greyed Out?

Tags: c#

I have a C# project with a database connection and a data set and some queries.

I added a Binding Source to the Main Form Design window at the bottom, and set it to my Database in the Properties. I also added a Binding Navigator and set it to my Binding Source.

I don't remember how to add a Table Adapter to the Main Form at the bottom. I thought I could drag and drop one from the toolbox, but it is greyed out.

Anyone know how I could add the Table Adapter in the Design window?

Comment: This is not related to the SQL _language_, so I removed that tag. Perhaps <ssms> or something suits better.

Comment: I disagree. If someone else has this issue they will likely be looking for C# and SQL tags. It is related to SQL as far as how Microsoft deals with SQL tables in Visual Studio, and how permissions are needed to auto-generate Table Adapters for developers like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue--you must have a DataSet added to your project, have the Data Source set correctly, and have permissions to view the Table columns.

To do this in Visual Studio 2022:

1. Make a new DB connection in SQL Server Object Explorer.  You will need to get permissions to view the table columns. To verify your DB permissions, open the table in Microsoft SQL Server Object Explorer. If you can view the table columns you have the enough permissions for Visual Studio to display the entire table schema in your Visual Studio Dataset.
2. In Visual Studio, in SQL Server Object Explorer, make a DB connection to your Database, and navigate to your table.

   Drag and drop your table onto the DataSet window for the DataSet you added.

   This will generate the Table view column details and a Table Adapter.  Once you have a Table Adapter you can configure your Queries using the Visual Studio Query Builder (Microsoft's Best DB tool for Developers IMO, unless you are a SQL Management Studio Expert).
3. In your Windows Form, add a DataGridView and set the data source to your TableAdapter.  This will make a table adapter and the icon will be on your form designer window at the bottom.  This is significant, because the designer will initialize and destroy/Dispose the table Adapter as needed. No memory leaks.